# SoapUI 5.3.0 Mac hangs on any use after installation

Tags: soapui

SoapUI 5.3.0 (latest open source version) Mac hangs on clean-install on MacOS 10.12.3 - with all presets suggested by the installer.

I tried rebooting & installing again - every time when you load the app it's just an eternal beach ball with no menus clickable - and requires a force quit - even after 5 minutes of just leaving it.

I've found nothing on Google about this

How can I fix this?!

Comment: Have you checked the log files? or try to start it from the terminal session and see what happens?

Comment: I looked at the logs but they didn't mean much. Terminal no idea how to do that although - should this not just work the first time you load it - pretty unimpressed TBH.

Comment: Go to SOAPUI_HOME/bin on command prompt / terminal and run 'soapui.sh` script

Answer (score 79):

I had the same issue and the solution described [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/SoapUI-Pro-5-1-2-hangs-on-Mac-OS-X-10-8-5/m-p/98340/highlight/true#M23585) worked for me.

Copying and pasting it here with the version OP asked:

> 1. Start ‘Activity Monitor’ and Force Kill your dead soapUI process. [Or
>      use Command-Option-Escape to force quit it.]
> 2. In Finder, `/Applications/SoapUI-5.3.0.app` > Show Package Contents.
> 3. Edit `/Applications/SoapUI-5.3.0.app/Contents/java/app/bin/soapui.sh`.
> 4. Uncomment this line `# JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"`. [In other words, remove the `#` to stop it being a comment.]
> 5. Edit `/Applications/SoapUI-5.3.0.app/Contents/vmoptions.txt`.
> 6. Add `-Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true`.
> 7. Start soapUI.

The question there was for version 5.1.2 which is more than 2 years old. I'm surprised for this still being an issue after that long.

Comment: Works for me in 5.3.0 on macOS as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is the most amazing thing I've seen on StackOverflow

Comment: Actually you dont need to edit soapui.sh, just adding the line in vmoptions.txt suffices.

Comment: I am using SoapUI v5.4.0 and this solution doesn't seem to be working :-( Application freezes while opening.

Comment: Same with Soap Ui 5.5.0 It was working fine for some weeks and suddenly I have an endless start screen and nothing happens. Might be related to a Mac Update :  I have now version 10.15.2

Comment: Just want to note for future users, this solution did work for me with SoapUI 5.5 and OS 10.15.2. IME, the browser component is a blank window that opens a few seconds after SoapUI launches.

Answer (score 13):

I found Phil Hudson's text when I had the same problem, worked for me with SoapUI 5.3.0: http://www.phil-hudson.com/fixing-soap-ui-5-2-1-hanging-on-osx-el-capitan/

From Phil's text (note that he wrote it for SoapUI 5.2.1):

> Basically, SOAP UI is using a bundled JDK for 1.7, but I use JDK 1.8 -
>   so we need to symlink it. Run the following:

```
cd /Applications/SoapUI-5.2.1.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre.bundle/Contents/Home
mv jre jre.old
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre jre
```

> Check that the symlink to your JDK is correct, versions might differ
>   so it's worth checking. If you've got it wrong, SOAPUI will throw a
>   startup error and tell you the JDK is missing.
>
> Restart SOAPUI and all will hopefully be good!

Comment: Phil's tip worked for me (thanks, Phil).  To add to your warning about taking care to type the symlink correctly, I expect this to fail again when we upgrade our JDK, thus invalidating the symlink.  Just something we (those of us using this tip) should keep in mind.

Comment: Bingo! Works great on 5.3.0!

Comment: Works for me (5.3.0 on macOS 10.13.1). Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this worked for me...

Alternatively, you can navigate to SoapUI*.app and do "Show Package Info" ( from popup menu ).
Then you should see Contents directory. Open Info.plist file for editing where you can add:

```
<key>soapui.jxbrowser.disable</key>
<string>true</string>
```

Comment: Program won't even load if I add that - can you elaborate on exactly what I need to add to the file?

Comment: it looks like stackoverflow removed my tags. this is what should be added to "Info.plist" -- "<key>soapui.jxbrowser.disable</key>
<string>true</string>"       (at least that is what worked for me.)

Comment: yep that's what I tried - now it just insta-crashes

Answer (score 2):

Auto Proxy Setting to false worked for me.

**Path:**`/Users/{your_user}/soapui_settings.xml`

**Setting:**`<con:setting id="ProxySettings@autoProxy">false</con:setting>`

Answer (score 2):

1) In Finder, go to `/Applications/SmartBear/soapUI-5.x.x` or sometimes under application directly `/Applications/soapUI-5.x.x`, then right click on it and choose `Show Package Contents`

2) Open `contents` dir, you should see file named `vmoptions.txt` open it and add the following line 
`-Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true`

3) In the same directory, I mean `contents`, open `java/app/bin/soapui.sh` and uncomment the following line by just removing `#`.

`# JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"`

So, it should be like this

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"`

4) If you were already opening SoapUI, make sure you force stop it from `Activity Monitor` or by just right clicking on it in the bottom toolbar and click `Force quit`.

5) Start SoapUI

References:

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/SoapUI-Pro-5-1-2-hangs-on-Mac-OS-X-10-8-5/m-p/98340/highlight/true#M23585

http://chanukadissanayake.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-fix-soapui-freeze-in-mac-os.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Mac OS 10.12.5, and the proxy was the problem, I just disabled the proxy and it worked![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KwqT.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need to add in Info.plist

```
<key>soapui.jxbrowser.disable</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (SoapUI 5.3.0 open source edition) - used Danilo's answer to fix the crashes.