# SoapUI 5.6.0 gets frozen after installation on Mac Big Sur 11.0.1

Tags: macos, soapui, macos-big-sur

Tried instructions from [SoapUI 5.3.0 Mac hangs on any use after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760917/soapui-5-3-0-mac-hangs-on-any-use-after-installation) that is basically:

- soapui.sh: uncomment # JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"
- vmoptions.txt: adding -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true

None of them worked. Any idea ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
cd /Applications/SoapUI-<<*version*>>.app/Contents/java/app/bin/
```

and then

```
run ./soapui.sh
```

you will see in logs freeze reasons.